# time mis-match during left join in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to join two table `all_clients` and `data_db` with two columns: `client_key` and `period`; Then calculate sum statistics for each clients and period from `all_clients` table. Minimum period of `all_clients` is '2020/05', however when I left join it to `data_db` resulted table has minimum period 2019/08. Indeed, resulted table `(df2)` should have minimum period equals to '2020/05';
what is error?
code of joining is below:

```
create table empl_df_bog as 
       with df1 as (select c.compinn
               ,c.client_key
               ,c.period
               ,max((case when nvl(s.dpd_max,0) > 90 then 1 else 0 end)) is_default 
               from all_clients c
               left join data_db s on c.client_key = s.client_key and 
               s.year_month between to_char(add_months(to_date(c.period,'YYYY/MM'), -12),'yyyy/mm') 
               and to_char(add_months(to_date(c.period,'YYYY/MM'), -1),'yyyy/mm')
               group by c.compinn, c.client_key, c.period)
,          df2 as(select compinn
              ,period
              ,avg(is_default) DR
              from df1
              group by compinn, period)
              select * from df2
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question. also where is 05/2020 in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about applying the same date / character conversion to the s.year_month field?  Does that give you the intended results?  I find when converting dates using TO_CHAR I have to do that with both dates in this case s.year_month.

After setting that up what does the results look like in your first CTE df1?

Comment: I convert s.year_moth to TO_CHAR and it works. Thank you!